# Monitor Firestore usage / performance for a session

Tags: performance, firebase, debugging, google-cloud-firestore, monitor

The Firebase Cloud Firestore console refers developers on the Usage tab to the Cloud Platform quotas page to view the usage of their app; however, this provides a very imprecise set of data to work on performance with?

I'm looking for a more granular option that shows the precise usage for a single session.

Is there a debug flag that can be passed to the Firestore SDK to log the number of document writes / reads / updates and bandwidth consumption for that session?

Or does anyone have a suggestion for a better method to analyse performance?

Comment: did you find the answer?